# Group claims not returned in JWT Token after manifest modification "All"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

IBM Cognos is not returning group claims after modifying the manifest of the application to "All" on the azure side.

Spoke with an IBM Cognos Engineer and he clearly stated that this is from the azure side. when we ran some fiddler and got the access_token of the application, decoded it but no group claims returned still.

Now we need to see something like this on the JWT body as shown in the image below:

[image]

[link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Azure-Active-Directory-now-with-Group-Claims-and-Application/ba-p/243862) to documentation that addresses this.

Comment: Does the user have more than 200 groups? In that case they won't be returned. Also, make sure the access token you are acquiring is for the same app which manifest you have modified.

Comment: In this case, the overrage limit does not apply. Y

Answer (score 0):

Adding  to @juunas answer,

1. does it have a claim by the name of "_claim_names" instead?
2. Are there multiple applications involved. did you change the manifest of the correct app?
3. Have you been working on this app for a while, you might be examining a cached token. Sign-out and sign-in again

Comment: "_claim_names" Does not apply.

Comment: We have a single App and directly try to modify the manifest to "ALL" for group claims

Comment: Not sure last option would play in, as we have repeatedly sign-out and back on client-side.

Comment: Thank you Kalyan for your input. is it possible to use MS graph explorer to query more? if yes, a help on a sample to be cool. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Graph explorer does not issue Jwt tokens, but you can check if the user has any [group memberships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0) in the first place. this is the exact Api (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link for instructions on modification to the AAD application manifest.  You will want to change the “groupMembershipClaims” property to “SecurityGroup” or all.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest

Also, note that the name of the security group won’t be shown... only the guid of the security group.

To see the name of the claim as a friendly string, you would want to use an “App Role”.  Edit the application manifest file in AAD to contain the names of the app roles you would like, and then you can edit users in your AAD Application and assign them to a role.  Note, if you only have AAD Basic then you can only assign users to one app role via the Azure Portal.  You’ll need to use the Graph API to assign the user to more than one app role, or you’ll need to upgrade to premium AAD.  Premium AAD subscriptions let you tie app roles to security groups, making it easier to apply multiple app roles to a user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

Comment: Thank you for your input here, I was expecting GUID not names. however, the GUID Isn't present still. I have the link you shared too.

Comment: Thank you for your input here, I was expecting GUID not names. however, the GUID Isn't present still. I have the link you shared too. 

The problem is we try to authenticate (successful) and grab the access token. using some tools to expose the properties, however we still not able to see the GUID for the group where a valid user is a member of same group. assigned to the App. 
---Any help to get around this would be greatly appreciated.